# React native how to apply pagination and loadmore to each specific tab separately?

Tags: react-native, pagination

so i currently have a screen with a horizontal scroll view that contains my category tabs. When a tab is pressed, a flatlist is rendered below with all the posts specific for that category (this part is working correctly).

When the screen initially loads the first tab is selected by default and all the posts for that tab are rendered below.

Now, i have applied pagination in my backend and when i tested it on postman it is working.

My problem is:

eg. if i select tab 1, the first page (page=0) posts get rendered then when i scroll down, the page count increases to 2 but no posts get rendered. Also, then when i select tab 2, the page count doesnt reset back 0 it continues from where it left off in tab 1.

in tab 1 if i keep scrolling down to page 10, then i select tab 2.

What i want is the page count in tab 2 to start at 0.

what is happening the page count in tab 2 starts at 10.

Here is my code:

```
const getCategoryPostsAPI = (id,page)=>client.get(`/categories/${id}?page=${page}`)

function tabScreen({ navigation,route }) {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const[page,setPage]=useState(0);

const loadPosts = async (id) => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await getCategoryPostsAPI(id,page) //API call
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
setError(false);

if(page===0){
  setPosts(response.data)
}else{    
setPosts([...posts,...response.data]);
}};

useEffect(() => {
loadPosts(1,page);
}, [page]);

const categories = [
{
label: "Sports",
id: 1,
},
{
label: "Fashion",
id: 2,
},
{
label: "News",
id: 3,
},
{
label: "Cooking",
id: 4,
},
{
label: "Education",
id: 5,
}]

const handleLoadMore = ()=>{
setPage(page+1);
}

const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports')

const setLabelFilter=label=>{
setLabel(label)
}

const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState()

const toggleBrands = (categoryId) => {
setCurrentCategoryId(categoryId)
setLabel(label)
};

return (

<ScrollView 
horizontal 
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
>
{categories.map(e=>(
        <TouchableOpacity 
            key={e.id}
            onPress={()=>{toggleBrands(e.id),
                          setLabelFilter(e.label),
                          loadPosts(id=e.id),                        
                          setPage(0) // here i am trying to set the page to 0 on tab click 
                                        but it is not working
                          }}
            selected={e.id === currentCategoryId}
            >
        <Text>{e.label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
))}
</ScrollView>

<FlatList
  data={currentCategoryId ? posts.filter(post=>post.categoryId===currentCategoryId
    ):posts.filter(post=>post.categoryId===1)} 
  keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
   <Card
      title={item.title}
      subTitle={item.subTitle}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, {post:item,index})}
    />
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.000001}
      initialNumToRender={10}
  )}
/>
```

I think i implemented my pagination wrong hence why my handleloadmore does not work because i have used the same handleloadmore in different screens and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the page to be reset to 0 when you click on another category and you want to paginate through the data when scrolling through a single category. If so, try this

```
const getCategoryPostsAPI = (id, page) => client.get(`/categories/${id}?page=${page}`);

const categories = [
  {
    label: "Sports",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    label: "Fashion",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    label: "News",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    label: "Cooking",
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    label: "Education",
    id: 5,
  }
];

function tabScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [label, setLabel] = useState(categories[0]?.label);
  const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState(1);

  const loadPosts = async (id, page = 0) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await getCategoryPostsAPI(id, page)
    setLoading(false);
    if (refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
    setError(false);
    if (page === 0) {
      setPosts(response.data)
    } else {
      setPosts([...posts, ...response.data]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page > 0)
      loadPosts(currentCategoryId, page);
  }, [page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(0);
    loadPosts(currentCategoryId, 0);
  }, [currentCategoryId])

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const setLabelFilter = label => {
    setLabel(label);
  };

  const toggleBrands = (categoryId) => {
    setCurrentCategoryId(categoryId);
  };

  const postsToBeDisplayed = () => posts.filter(post => post.categoryId === currentCategoryId);

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        {categories.map(e => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={e.id}
            onPress={() => {
              toggleBrands(e.id);
              setLabelFilter(e.label);
            }}
            selected={e.id === currentCategoryId}
          >
            <Text>{e.label}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>

      <FlatList
        data={postsToBeDisplayed()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <Card
            title={item.title}
            subTitle={item.subTitle}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, { post: item, index })}
          />
        )}
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.000001}
        initialNumToRender={10}
        keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      />
    </>
  )
};
```

However, if you want to implement the tab feature, I would recommend using [react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view). This will make the whole process a lot easier.

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me, really appreciate it. I have tried the code above it wasnt working but then i managed to make it work by doing the following: 1) i removed the if(page>0) from the first useEffect 2) In the touchableOpacity onPress i added loadPosts(id=e.id) and setPage(0)

Comment: i also have another question if possible, when the screen loads by default the first tab is selected but the posts for that tab do not load until i press the tab again. How do i make it so that when the screen loads the posts for the first tab load as well?

Comment: Initially when i load the page, tab 1 is selected by default but my currentCategory is undefined hence no posts get loaded

Comment: From the code, the posts are fetched on the basis of currentCategoryId. The currentCategoryId is initialized with the value '1'.

Comment: yes but when the screen loads, the first tab is selected by default since i set it like this const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports')
 when i do console.log(currentCategoryId) i get undefined and no posts are loaded then when i press the same tab again console.log(currentCategoryId) returns 1 and posts load

Comment: share your latest code. Aren't you setting the currentCategoryId as 1 initially?

Comment: my latest code is exactly the same as the one you provide but with these changes: i removed the if(page>0) from the first useEffect and In the touchableOpacity onPress i added loadPosts(id=e.id) and setPage(0), do you still require my latest code or is that ok?

Comment: In the code provided, currentCategoryId is intialized with 1 as const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState(1);. Technically you don't need to call the loadposts and setPage functions in the touchableopacity onPress as it will be run as a side effect when currentCategoryId's value change.

Comment: let me give this a try in my code i was still using const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState() not const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState(1)

Comment: Do i still need to set const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports') or i dont need it?

Comment: You can keep the label as it is. from the above code, I don't see any usage of that label variable though. What exactly are you using it for?

Comment: i am using it in my setLabelFilter function, i dont need it?

Comment: i tried this   const [label, setLabel] = useState(categories[0]?.label);
and i got an error undefined is not an object (evaluating categories[0])

Comment: With setLabelFilter function, you are simply changing the value of the label var. what's exactly the use of that label. Are you using it anywhere for any logic?

Comment: no, i just want to change the tab when a user clicks on any of the tabs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225450/discussion-between-nithinpp-and-kd12345).